# Дублирование кода, как упростить

Tags: javascript, jquery, инспекция-кода

Подскажите пожалуйста. имеются три переменные, для которых есть повторяющиеся действия. Каким образом упростить написание или убрать дублирование кода?

```
$('.main_btna').on('click', function() {
    $('.overlay').fadeIn();
    $('.modal').animate({
        opacity: 'show',
        top: '0'
    },
        1000);
});

$('.main_btn').on('click', function() {
    $('.overlay').fadeIn();
    $('.modal').animate({
        opacity: 'show',
        top: '0'
    },
        1000);
});

$('.schedule').on('click', function() {
    $('.overlay').fadeIn();
    $('.modal').animate({
        opacity: 'show',
        top: '0'
    },
        1000);
});
```

Comment: вынести функцию. В `on` указывать имя функции

Answer (score 2):

Сделай [общий селектор](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B), вот так:

```js
$('.main_btna, .main_btn, .schedule').click(()=>{
    $('.overlay').fadeIn();
    $('.modal').animate({
        opacity: 'show',
        top: '0'
    }, 1000);
});
```

+Если у тебя всего один `.overlay` [и\или] `.modal`, лучше дописать к ним `:first` (без пробела), чтоб jq не искал по древу эл-ты

Comment: А ещё лучше сделать класс `.js-modal` например, и повесить их на все элементы, которые будут выполнять код, ну а в коде указать `$('.js-modal')`